# AngularFire2 with Observables doesn't catch $ref property

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

So I started using AngularFire2 (version 4.0.0-rc.1) and stuck on this problem:

```
  getWishlist$(): FirebaseListObservable<{}> {
    return <FirebaseListObservable<{}>>this.store.select(getFirebaseUID)
      .filter(res => res.isAuthenticated)
      .map(res => res.UserUUID)
      .switchMap(uid => this.db.list(`/wishlist/${uid}/products`));
  }
```

So after switchMap operator it should return me original Observable from `this.db.list()` which is FirebaseListObservable, but it doesn't happen and my next code has an error in runtime.

```
  this.accountService.getWishlist$().$ref
    .orderByChild('pk').equalTo(designer.pk).once('value', (data) => {
       if (!data.exists()) {
         this.accountService.getWishlist$().push(designer);
       }
    })
```

And error is:

```
Cannot read property 'orderByChild' of undefined
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question that was asked via a [repo issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1008):

> That isn't how `switchMap` - and RxJS, in general - works. The observable returned by an operator depends upon the observable upon which the operator is called. Said observable can implement [`lift`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues/60) to return an observable instance of the same type.
>
> The AngularFire2 observables implement `lift` - see [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/4.0.0-rc.0/src/database/firebase_list_observable.ts#L16-L22) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/4.0.0-rc.0/src/database/firebase_object_observable.ts#L12-L18) - but that makes no difference in the situation you have described, ...

The observable that's returned from your `switchMap` call is the observable that has been lifted from `this.store.select` - not from `this.db.list`.

Comment: So just extending my question to issue that You link provided. If I call .switch() operator that doesn't change anything to situation, $ref will still be undefined, because I never did subscription. Is that correct? So for me it's better to have .map() subscribe, receive FirebaseList/ObjectObservable and tie it to Component class if I understand that correctly. That is kinda sad because I would expect to have more of my logic in services...

Comment: Without a call to `subscribe`, nothing will happen. If you look at your original `getWishlist$` method, it should be clear that it cannot work without a `subscribe`, as it's obtaining the `UID` from the store observable and is using that to create a Firebase ref - indirectly, via the AngularFire2 list - so it's not possible for the return value to be an object containing the ref.